# How to specify version for Android aar?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, aar

I'm creating a aar from my library project. But if I add it in another project its treated as "unspecified". (name="MyLibrary-unspecified") If I click the .aar its also saying "unknown (version unknown)". How to set up this properly? (I name the file MyLibrary-1.1.0.aar but this does not help)

Comment: Are you deploying the aar in a maven repo?

Comment: No. Only adding it to other projects over New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR Package.

Comment: In this case it is just a flat aar. There are no version.